# How to create triangle in SpriteKit (Swift 2)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I did it with **SKSpritenode**

```
 func AddTopTriangels() {

        TopTriangel = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Top-Triangels.png")
        TopTriangel.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height/2 + 370)
        TopTriangel.size = CGSize.init(width: 440, height: 35)
        addChild(TopTriangel)
    }
```

But i want to create it with **SKShapenode** , how i can do it?

[image]

Comment: You should update your question with what you have tried so far. That way you will probably get your answer. Otherwise you are risking your question being closed (or downvoted). In the meanwhile see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: Do you want a rectangular triangle image with physic body of triangle shape?

Comment: I need to create triangle shape and yes , with physic body of triangle shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create `SKSpriteNode` as you did in the question and just attach physic body to it with triangle shape:

```
    var trianglePath = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(trianglePath, nil, -TopTriangel.size.width/2, -TopTriangel.size.height/2)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, TopTriangel.size.width/2, -TopTriangel.size.height/2)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, 0, TopTriangel.size.height/2)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, -TopTriangel.size.width/2, -TopTriangel.size.height/2)
    TopTriangel.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: trianglePath)
```

You can add this line:

```
sceneView.showsPhysics = true
```

to make sure the shape match your image (`SKSpriteNode`), just remember to remove it after debugging.

Comment: listen , in iPhone6s+ my pic looking bad. and i want to fix it , i need triangle without physics

Comment: Have you added image x3 this is the image displayed by iPhone6+. You you want to the image looking good on all of the phones you should have three version on the same image for no retina, for retina (x2) and for 6+ (x3). Do some researches on this topic.

Comment: @omer15 Just to add (based on your comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304214/how-to-create-a-separation-between-the-two-objects-spritekit-swift/34311505?noredirect=1#comment56375599_34311505) ) that you can create SKShapeNode from a path (trianglePath from Greg's answer) as well as to create node's physics body by using that same path.

Comment: but here i did it with image.